# type-safe Entity Objects with heavy data

Tags: c++, sql, entity

Currently, our system uses something similar to Java Entity Beans, though it's written in C++/SQL. Essentially, there are classes that (more or less) symbolize tables, and instances of these classes are equivalent to table-rows. I want to add that this approach is flawed to begin with, see this famous essay: http://blogs.tedneward.com/2006/06/26/The+Vietnam+Of+Computer+Science.aspx
On the other hand, it works well, as long as you accept that it will result in something that is impure and a bit of a hack at times.

Nevertheless, the actual problem is as follows: While many of these entities are relatively light in memory footprint (a dozen columns containing ints, floats and strings) and result in good performance, some of them are really not.

1. Some contain binary blobs such as meshes, or pictures. One could argue that these should not be stored in the DB to begin with, but that's another topic.
2. Some don't actually contain a lot of data (when measured in bytes), but fetching the full set is a very big and rather slow query due to the number of joins involved.

The twist: These "fat" objects often get used without their full data. Imagine you have a "Passport" class that contains biometric data, family relation trees, but also the name and birth-date. If you want to display a list of passports, you only need the basic data.

What I am currently doing is to create a Passport instance, but fill it in two steps. The first step only adds the easy fields, but leaves the heavy fields open (as NULL). The instance can later be passed to a function that will add all the difficult fields. This works without a hitch, as long as I don't make a mistake and use a "shallow" instance where I need the "full" version. Sure, I can add all kinds of internal checks, but not only does that scale poorly (reimplementing them for every entity, more or less), it is also very error-prone.

My problem is thus: **I would like to distinguish the two versions at compile-time**, not just at run-time. That way, I would catch most errors before they ever happen.

The only idea that seems to work is to split the two parts into two entity-halves, and pass them around as tuples. If the second tuple is missing, obviously the fat data wasn't loaded yet. While that works, it results in dastardly syntax:

```
std::vector< EntityTuple<EmptyPassport, FullPassport>>
```

And all type-safety I get is at the cost of readability, which isn't a great improvement. Currently, I have no better ideas, and suspect this to be actually impossible in C++, but I could be wrong. Non-C++-suggestions are welcome too, there might be a better way to do this in the future. Of course, if anyone can make a good point as to why this is impossible, I'll accept that also.

Answer (score 1):

**Overview**

Let me suggest some ideas to handle "Heavy" properties like blobs, images, files. Remember, there is not "one solution for all". I personally reject the idea of a "load all heavy properties" flag, & suggest alternative ideas.

Before , I continue, please ignore small syntax or logic errors, and focus in the logic of the code examples.

**[1] Define Example**

First, let's start with a simple example:

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
  public:
    int     Key;
    char    FirstName[150];
    char    LastName[150];
    Image*  Photo;    // <- picture
    Blob*   Contract; // <- scanned contract
}; // class
```

First of all, you do not have to load or do not load, the "heavy" properties, because the "Entity" model or other programming technique says so.

In fact, I wouldn't add a flag for heavy objects, because that means load all "heavy" properties or do not load any "heavy" property at all. And, sometimes you may have to load some of them, but, not all.

**[2] Load Properties**

Usually, the logic of a program, indicates, when to load the properties.

The common practice its to use a different constructor, for each case:

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
  public:
    int     Key;
    char    FirstName[150];
    char    LastName[150];
    Image*  Photo;
    Blob*   Contract;

  public:
    // --> generic constructor
    EmployeeClass()
    {
      Key = 0;
      strcpy(FirstName, "");
      strcpy(LastName, "");
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 
    } // EmployeeClass()

    // --> "light" constructor
    EmployeeClass
    (
      int   AKey,
      char* AFirstName,
      char* ALastName
    )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName;
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 
    } // EmployeeClass()

    // --> "heavy" constructor
    EmployeeClass
    (
      int    AKey,
      char*  AFirstName,
      char*  ALastName,
      Image* APhoto,
      Blob*  AContract
    )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName;
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = APhoto; 
      Contract = AContract; 
    } // EmployeeClass()

    void Insert();
}; // class

void Test()
{
   ...
   int AKey = 0;
   char AFirstName[150];
   char ALastName[150];
   Image* APhoto = null;
   Blob*  AContract = null;

   // --> calling "light" constructor

   AKey = 1;
   strcpy(AFirstName, "Mary");
   strcpy(ALastName, "Thompson");

   EmployeeClass* AEmployee = new EmployeeClass
      (AKey, AFirstName, ALastName);

   AEmployee->Insert();

   // --> calling "heavy" constructor

   AKey = 2;
   strcpy(AFirstName, "John");
   strcpy(ALastName, "Doe");

   Image* APhoto = LoadPhoto();
   Blob*  AContract = LoadContract();

   EmployeeClass* AEmployee = new EmployeeClass
      (AKey, AFirstName, ALastName, APhoto, AContract);

   AEmployee->Insert();

   // --> calling "dummy" constructor,
   // --> more work, but, more flexible

   AKey = 1;
   strcpy(AFirstName, "Mary");
   strcpy(ALastName, "Thompson");

   EmployeeClass* AEmployee = new EmployeeClass();
     AEmployee->Key = AKey;
     strcpy(AEmployee->FirstName, AFirstName);
     strcpy(AEmployee->LastName, ALastName);
     AEmployee->Photo = LoadPhoto();
     AEmployee->Contract = LoadContract();
   AEmployee->Insert();

   ...
} // void Test()
```

Many developers only use the "common light constructor", & reject the idea of having several constructors.

**[3] Additional Help**

Let's skip, for a moment, the "heavy" properties, will continue later.

This is suggestion that many C/C++ developers don't like, but, I personally find very useful when dealing with entity objects. I use the "two step initialization".

For each entity class, I declare a constructor, with no parameters that clears the fields,
and, add, a virtual method, with a very specific identifier, that takes the role of a constructor.

Then, I may add several virtual methods that work as constructors, like deciding wheter loading the "heavy" properties or not.

So, the previous example become something like this:

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
  public:
    bool F_EmployeeClass_IsReady;
  public:
    int     Key;
    char    FirstName[150];
    char    LastName[150];
    Image*  Photo;
    Blob*   Contract;

  public:
    // --> only generic constructor
    Employee()
    {
      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = false;

      Key = 0;
      strcpy(FirstName, "");
      strcpy(LastName, "");
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 
    } // EmployeeClass()

    virtual bool IsReady()
    {
      return F_EmployeeClass_IsReady;
    } // bool IsReady(...)

    // --> works like "generic" constructor from previous example
    virtual void Create()
    {
      Key = 0;
      strcpy(FirstName, "");
      strcpy(LastName, "");
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 

      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = true;
    } // void Create()

    // --> works like "light" constructor from previous example
    virtual void CreateLight
      (
        int   AKey,
        char* AFirstName,
        char* ALastName
      )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName);
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 

      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = true;
    } // void CreateLight()

    virtual void Destroy()
    {
      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = false;
    } // void Destroy()

    // --> works like "heavy" constructor from previous example
    virtual void CreateHeavy
      (
        int   AKey,
        char* AFirstName,
        char* ALastName,
        Image* APhoto,
        Blob*  AContract
      )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName);
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = APhoto; 
      Contract = AContract; 

      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = true;
    } // void CreateHeavy()

    void Insert();
}; // class

void Test()
{
   ...
   int AKey = 0;
   char AFirstName[150];
   char ALastName[150];
   Image* APhoto = null;
   Blob*  AContract = null;

   // --> calling "light" constructor

   AKey = 1;
   strcpy(AFirstName, "Mary");
   strcpy(ALastName, "Thompson");

   EmployeeClass* AEmployee = new EmployeeClass();
   AEmployee->CreateLight(AKey, AFirstName, ALastName);

     AEmployee->Insert();

   AEmployee->Destroy();
   delete AEmployee;

   // --> calling "heavy" constructor

   AKey = 2;
   strcpy(AFirstName, "John");
   strcpy(ALastName, "Doe");

   Image* APhoto = LoadPhoto();
   Blob*  AContract = LoadContract();

   EmployeeClass* AEmployee = new EmployeeClass();
   AEmployee->CreateHeavy
     (AKey, AFirstName, ALastName, APhoto, AContract);

     AEmployee->Insert();

   AEmployee->Destroy();
   delete AEmployee;

   // --> calling "dummy" constructor,
   // --> more work, but, more flexible

   AKey = 1;
   strcpy(AFirstName, "Mary");
   strcpy(ALastName, "Thompson");

   EmployeeClass* AEmployee = new EmployeeClass();
   AEmployee->Create();

     AEmployee->Key = AKey;
     strcpy(AEmployee->FirstName, AFirstName);
     strcpy(AEmployee->LastName, ALastName);
     AEmployee->Photo = LoadPhoto();
     AEmployee->Contract = LoadContract();

     AEmployee->Insert();

   AEmployee->Destroy();
   delete AEmployee;

   ...
} // void Test()
```

In the previous example, each entity is created using 2 steps, the "dummy" constructor, and a complementary method, different for each case, with a meaningful identifier, useful when choosing how to prepare an entity object.

Same goes for the destruction of each object.

**[4] Heavy Properties methods**

Finally, you may want to add some method that are in charge of loading the "heavy" properties when needed. Sometimes are called explicitly, and sometimes, called automatically.

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
  public:
    bool F_EmployeeClass_IsReady;
  public:
    int     Key;
    char    FirstName[150];
    char    LastName[150];
    Image*  Photo;
    Blob*   Contract;

  public:
    // --> only generic constructor
    Employee()
    {
      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = false;

      Key = 0;
      strcpy(FirstName, "");
      strcpy(LastName, "");
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 
    } // EmployeeClass()

    virtual bool IsReady()
    {
      return F_EmployeeClass_IsReady;
    } // bool IsReady(...)

    void LoadPhoto();
    void SavePhoto();

    void LoadContract();
    void SaveContract();

    // --> works like "generic" constructor from previous example
    virtual void Create()
    {
      Key = 0;
      strcpy(FirstName, "");
      strcpy(LastName, "");
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 

      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = true;
    } // void Create()

    // --> works like "light" constructor from previous example
    virtual void CreateLight
      (
        int   AKey,
        char* AFirstName,
        char* ALastName
      )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName);
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 

      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = true;
    } // void CreateLight()

    virtual void Destroy()
    {
      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = false;
    } // void Destroy()

    // --> works like "heavy" constructor from previous example
    virtual void CreateHeavy
      (
        int   AKey,
        char* AFirstName,
        char* ALastName,
        Image* APhoto,
        Blob*  AContract
      )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName);
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = APhoto; 
      Contract = AContract; 

      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = true;
    } // void CreateHeavy()


    // --> works like "heavy" constructor from previous example
    virtual void CreateAndLoad
      (
        int   AKey,
        char* AFirstName,
        char* ALastName
      )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName);
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);

      LoadPhoto();
      LoadContract; 

      F_EmployeeClass_IsReady = true;
    } // void CreateAndLoad()

    void Insert();
}; // class

void Test()
{
   ...
   int AKey = 0;
   char AFirstName[150];
   char ALastName[150];
   Image* APhoto = null;
   Blob*  AContract = null;

   // --> calling "load" constructor

   AKey = 1;
   strcpy(AFirstName, "Mary");
   strcpy(ALastName, "Thompson");

   EmployeeClass* AEmployee = new EmployeeClass();
   AEmployee->CreateLoad(AKey, AFirstName, ALastName);

     AEmployee->Insert();

   AEmployee->Destroy();
   delete AEmployee;

   ...
} // void Test()
```

With the additional methods, you may have a [fake] constructor that ignores them, and don't load the "heavy" properties, a [fake] constructor that call them. Or, use the [fake] constructor that doesn't use them, & explicitly call the loader for a specific "heavy" property.

These, helps also, if you load images from a filesystem path, & save them into a database fields, or viceversa, load files from a database field, & save them to a filesystem path.

Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. This is very close to what we are currently doing, and it works well enough. It is, however, not type-safe in how it handles the heavy content.

Comment: @Kajetan Abt: My sugg. was intended to ("think different"), handle the properties in an alternative way, known from start wheter its going to require those properties, and not detect after, if they where loaded. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

[EDIT] Your "flag" idea it's ok.

In another answer I provide an alternative solution, I personally, think its a better solution, but, doesn't mean that your idea is wrong.

The following example, that I DO have applied in some cases, its the same "flag" idea, a possible implementation, you may want or not want to follow.

Example:

```
public class EmployeeClass
{
  // --> logic fields
  private:
    bool    F_HeavyLoaded; 

  // --> "entity" fields
  public:
    int     Key;
    char    FirstName[150];
    char    LastName[150];
    Image*  Photo;    // <- picture
    Blob*   Contract; // <- scanned contract

  public:
  // --> constructors

    EmployeeClass
    (
      int   AKey,
      char* AFirstName,
      char* ALastName
    )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName;
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = null; 
      Contract = null; 

      F_HeavyLoaded = false;
    } // EmployeeClass()

    // --> "heavy" constructor
    EmployeeClass
    (
      int    AKey,
      char*  AFirstName,
      char*  ALastName,
      Image* APhoto,
      Blob*  AContract
    )
    {
      Key = AKey;
      strcpy(FirstName, AFirstName;
      strcpy(LastName, ALastName);
      Photo = APhoto; 
      Contract = AContract; 

      F_HeavyLoaded = true;
    } // EmployeeClass()

  public:
    // --> "entity" methods


    bool IsHeavyLoaded() { return F_HeavyLoaded; }

    void Insert();
    void Update();
    void Delete();
}; // class
```

In this example, there is a private flag field, called "F_IsHeavyLoaded", it can be modified only in the constructors. Its publically available as read only, using a function.

Cheers.

Comment: Again, this works, but it doesn't solve my problem that I want to check at *compile time* whether an entity is loaded or not.